# Android: Calculate price from clicked items in listview. App crashes in total activity Logcat:Invalid float: ""

Tags: java, android

Im a noob in this so please bear with me. I have a listview of food and drinks with price then a proceed button which will show the order summary and total amount in other activity. After I click some items then click the proceed button, the app crash "Unfortunately appname has stopped." But when I click proceed button without clicking any items it displays the layout of the order summary. Therefore the error occurs in the passing of data. In logcat I noticed first Invalid float: ""  I have no idea how to fix this. 
I used SQLite for database of items

---

This is the code of activity for order summary and total amount where the error seems to appear.

```
package edu.sti.snapchit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.lang.String;


public class TotalsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

MyApp mApp;
EditText et_summary;
TextView tv_total;
Button btn_code;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.totals);
    btn_code = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_code);
    mApp=((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
    et_summary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_summary);
    tv_total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
    et_summary.setText(mApp.getGlobalVarValue());
    String str = mApp.getGlobalVarValue();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"Php");
    String test="";
    float total=0;
    int count =0;

    while(st.hasMoreElements())
    {
        test = st.nextElement().toString().substring(0,1);
        if(count>0)
            total += Float.parseFloat(test);
        count++;
    }

    tv_total.setText("Total:" + total+"");
    mApp.setGlobalClear();
    btn_code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(TotalsActivity.this, GeneratorActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}


public boolean isFloat(String input)
{

    try
    {
        Float.parseFloat(input);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

---

Total XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="            Order Summary            "
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/textV"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.07"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp">



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="267dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.55"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:hint="Summary"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total  : "
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.07"
        android:id="@+id/tv_total"/>



</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_code"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Proceed to Qr Code Generator"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Code for Food Activity which contains the listview

```
package edu.sti.snapchit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.HashMap;


public class NewFoodsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MyApp mApp;
private HashMap<String, Location> locations;
ListView listView1;
SQLiteDatabase db;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("Foods_DB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_foods);
    locations = loadLocationData();
    addListenerButton();
    initializeUI();
}
public void initializeUI()
{
    String[] foodies = getFoodNames();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foodies);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
private String[] getFoodNames()
{
    String[] foodies = new String[locations.size()];
    foodies = locations.keySet().toArray(foodies);
    return foodies;
}
private void displaySelectedFoodInfo(String foodName)
{

}
public void showMessage(String title,String message)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
private HashMap<String, Location>loadLocationData()
{
    HashMap<String, Location>locations = new HashMap<String, Location>();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_foods order by food_id 
asc",null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
        locations.put("- "+c.getString(1).toString()+" [Php 
"+c.getString(2).toString()+"]", new Location(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)),c.getString(1).toString(),Double.parseDouble(c.getString(2))));

    }
    return locations;
}
public void addListenerButton()
{
    final Context context = this;
    Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    Button btnProceed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnProceed);
    Button btn_drinks = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_drinks);
    Button btn_foods = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_foods);
    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> Arg0, View view, int 
position, long id) {
                    Object o = listView1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String pen = o.toString();

                    mApp=((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
                    mApp.setGlobalVarValue(pen);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Added" + 
""+ pen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            }
    );
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewAddFoods.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btnProceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TotalsActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btn_foods.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewFoodsActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btn_drinks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewDrinksActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

---

Food XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Food Items"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_foods"
        android:layout_width="192dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Foods"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_drinks"
        android:layout_width="192dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Drinks"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_width="192dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Add Snacks"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnProceed"
    android:layout_width="192dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Proceed"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

MyApp

```
package edu.sti.snapchit;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApp extends Application{
private String mGlobalVarValue="";

public String getGlobalVarValue(){
    return mGlobalVarValue;
}
public void setGlobalVarValue(String str){
    mGlobalVarValue += str+"\n";
}
public void setGlobalClear(){
    mGlobalVarValue="";
}
```

}

---

Location

```
package edu.sti.snapchit;

public class Location {

private int id;
private String name;
private double price;


public Location(int id,String name, double price){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.id + " " +this.name +" " +this.price;
}
}
```

---

This is the colored red text in LOGCAT

> 02-20 04:37:23.624 1447-1447/edu.sti.snapchit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{edu.sti.snapchit/edu.sti.snapchit.TotalsActivity}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
>                                                                       at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>                                                                       at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:289)
>                                                                       at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
>                                                                       at edu.sti.snapchit.TotalsActivity.onCreate(TotalsActivity.java:40)
>                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
>                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
>
> 02-20 04:37:29.372 1494-1494/edu.sti.snapchit E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>
> 02-20 04:37:30.592 1494-1494/edu.sti.snapchit E/OpenGLRenderer:
>   Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache 02-20 04:37:30.616
>   1494-1494/edu.sti.snapchit E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE
>   from Caches::initConstraints()

Ps. Yes I did followed a youtube tutorial in making this app. The app in vid is working perfectly while mine crashes. Either I missed something but I checked the code like 10 times or either there are parts of the vid been skipped. The uploader havent respond for days :(

I almost forgot there might also another reason that caused this. In TotalsActivity the method isFloat is never used. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IxMM.png)

Comment: Read the stacktrace. It tells you ``java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""``. That means that you try to execute ``Float.parseFloat`` with ``""`` (an empty String) as a parameter. Since that cannot be converted to a float value, you get an Exception. Find you why you pass an empty String.

Comment: parse only when str is not empty simply place check if  (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str.trim())) then do parse float.

Comment: It  will have value if I clicked an item thats why I have this test = st.nextElement().toString().substring(0,1); from the MyApp and string tokenizer.  So far I manage to display the clicked Items but still fail to parse for calculation. It now say Invalid float: "-"  the dash is the first character in every row in list. :/

Answer (score -1):

If you've read error log carefully then it would be easy. Anyways. just replace below code

```
package edu.sti.snapchit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.lang.String;


public class TotalsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

MyApp mApp;
EditText et_summary;
TextView tv_total;
Button btn_code;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.totals);
    btn_code = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_code);
    mApp=((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
    et_summary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_summary);
    tv_total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
    et_summary.setText(mApp.getGlobalVarValue());
    String str = mApp.getGlobalVarValue();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"Php");
    String test="";
    float total=0;
    int count =0;

    while(st.hasMoreElements())
    {
        test = st.nextElement().toString().substring(0,1);
        if(count>0 && test !=null && !test.isEmpty()){
            total += Float.parseFloat(test);
           }
        count++;
    }

    tv_total.setText("Total:" + total+"");
    mApp.setGlobalClear();
    btn_code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(TotalsActivity.this, GeneratorActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}


public boolean isFloat(String input)
{

    if(input.isEmpty() || input == null)
       return false;

    try
    {
        Float.parseFloat(input);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you but it still crashes. Oh I forgot it also has warning that the method isFloat is never used. :/

Comment: Nothing changed sir :(